# How to gather multiple checkbox values in a form using php

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, checkbox

Im trying to gather checkbox informtion in a php form. Everythig else is working perfectly, but when selecting 5/10 checkboxes it only gives me the last one checked. When using "services[]" array, it just emails back "services:array"
Any ideas would be great.

Thanks.
(this is the PHP im using)

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$services = $_POST['services'];

$message = $_POST['message'];
$changes = $_POST['changes'];
$found_me = $_POST['found_me'];
```

(this is the HTML thread)

```
<label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="silver" class="silver">
        Silver Pack (Website)
        </label>
```

Comment: $services will be an array, check it like var_dump($services)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are posting any element with having square brackets `[]` in the end, you are posting an array of multiple elements.

You are posting checboxes with `name` `services[]`, so you will get array in posted form.

Also, if you have 10 services checkboxes, only those will be posted which will be checked.

To deal with this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="silver" class="silver">
```

in PHP, use foreach loop for all checkboxes.

```
<?php
if (! empty($_POST['services'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['services'] as $service) {
    // YOU ARE GETTING POSTED VALUES HERE.
    // NOW, $service will have values like: silver, ...
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: @JoeyG, if my answer worked for you,  please accept it as solution.